# Retrieve a single field's version history from SharePoint

Tags: column, version-history

My company uses a SharePoint list as an asset inventory database.  One of the fields is a Notes field.  I am able to pull the current contents of the field by linking to the list in MSAccess, but I would like to pull all previously-entered notes.  I am doing this so we can track repairs performed on a per-machine basis, attached to the item.  I would be searching by Item Title.

I would like to NOT interact with the website when I am pulling this.  Any other approach would be helpful, so long as I can view the text contents and dates when the text was changed.

As a second step, it would be nice to add/append a note to the item from the same interface, whatever that will be.  However, the first step of collecting the notes is more important.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might get more answers on SharePoint stackexchange. Also, which version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: 2010, sorry. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that.

Comment: By the way, the following is pretty close to what I'm looking for, I just need a way to trigger it outside of the SP web interface (Like Access, Excel, etc.). http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2012/07/export-version-history-of-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest a different approach, without using version history:: create a SharePoint list called Notes, with a column being a lookup to the Asset list. You can then group or filter the Notes list, no need for the version history.

I use this method myself. You can extend it byond notes, and build other lists to track maintenance tasks, incidents, etc.

To pull all the notes related to an asset, go to the asset dispform and use the "Related Lists" feature.

Comment: I really liked this approach, but discovered that the Notes column in that list is of the "Append to previous" kind.  this column does not show up in the list of columns to look up in the list. Also, It unfortunately links to an MSAccess front-end, so if I change this particular list item to non-versioned, I will need to relink the tables and redeploy (this is not happening).  I think I discovered that my whole issue is the fact that this field is versioned as opposed to a 50-line notes field. it makes sense that the creator did it this way but it's preventing me from doing what I need.

Comment: Correct, this is how that form works: it retrieves and displays the previous versions. btw if you are bound to Access be sure to anticipate any migration to the 2013 version as there are some changes.

Comment: When I create a new list, and add a Column of type "Lookup (info already on site)", I can add any column from my Inventory list EXCEPT Notes. It just doesn't show up in the dropdown in the "Additional column settings" nor the radio-button list. See link for screenshot, not sure if I'm doing what you're telling me. What the heck could be different about this field than the others? [Thanks for the Access tip, I did run into an issue and ended up just having 2010 installed alongside 2013.] https://www.dropbox.com/s/c17ehqg5u9g5i5b/spNotes.png

Comment: You can only add fields of type "simple text" (single line text, number, date). My suggestion was to discard your current Notes field and create a new list called Notes with a multiline field.